# How do I embed a Teams Channel Chat in a Web App

Tags: microsoft-teams

I looking for a little guidance. I  have a need to display the chat content from a MS Teams channel into my web app.

The user of my web app will see the MS Team channel chat and be able to comment all of this in the web app.

What is the best / most appropriate approach for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to show a Teams chat inside any other Web App. You could get the messages in a Teams channel using [List Channel Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) and post your messages using [Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating) but it not possible to directly show the Entire Teams channel chat in your web app.